# Using appcompat support library, Overflow not working on API 7?

Tags: android-appcompat

I am using v7 appcompat support library. The action items work showing in the actionBar just fine on either newer or older devices.

However, I don't get Overflow on API 7.  For example:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuAction"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_directions"
        android:title="@string/barButtonTitle"
        appcompat:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuAction1"
        android:title="@android:string/untitled"
        appcompat:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

`appcompat:showAsAction="always|withText"` works, it shows as an Action Item in ActionBar.  However, `appcompat:showAsAction="never"` doesn't show in the Overflown as it does in newer platform.  It is hidden on the bottom, and revealed when you pressed on the older menu button.

Is that the intended behavior from appcompat support library? or am I missing anything to get the Overflow working on the older platform?

Comment: Noticed the same issue, so I found your question. Did you find a solution to get the overflow menu to show? Maybe it's intended indeed as those API7 devices will always have a menu button.

Comment: never get the overflow working on API 7.  Although it is not a show stopper for me since the item still can be revealed by old menu button.  still wondering if this is just a bug that Google is working on it?

Answer (score 2):

> Is that the intended behavior from appcompat support library?

Yes, it is

---

The overflow button (3 dots) is only shown if the devices don't have a hardware menu button.

Every gingerbread-device must have a menu-button, so the overflow button won´t show on API level 7

For more information about this topic, the following blog-post might be interesting:
http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for your answer. But it seems to be incomplete. "So... what?" might be the question :-). Thanks for editing/completing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The overflow do not show in older versions as far as I have researched, but you can use in your manifest (inside the activity level) the following (for pre ICS):

```
<activity ...>
<meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
               android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
</activity>
```

this will show the action itens at the bottom of the display, you have to add this in all activities you want to have this behavior. For ICS > you can add the following in the manifest at the application level, this will have effect in all activities.

```
<application android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
</application>
```